# AngularJS tooltip without bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm fairly new to AngularJS, and working on a project that is very restrictive towards external dependencies; in fact, Bootstrap is ruled out, and yet, I have to implement a "tooltip" directive.

I'm trying to do it using mouseenter and mouseleave events, but I wonder how can I use the directive's own attribute as the tooltip's content?

It'd be used like this:

```
<a id='someLink' my-tooltip='The content that I want to show'>Trigger</a>
```

Being quite green on UI development, can anyone tell me how I could add the necessary HTML/CSS to make this work through the directive?

Comment: There is an Angularjs version of [bootstrap here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip) that is written by the angular team.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear in the question; angular-ui is also ruled out. AFAIK the person responsible wants to keep the client as thin as it can possibly be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kbo0L6vo/)**

```
app.directive("tooltip", function () {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        $(element).on("mouseover", function () {
            $(this).append("<span>"+ attrs.tooltip +"</span>");
        });

        $(element).on("mouseout", function () {
            $(this).find("span").remove();
        });

        scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
            $(element).off("mouseover");
            $(element).off("mouseout");                
        });
    }
  };
});
```

**CSS** **[Source](http://www.cssportal.com/css-tooltip-generator/)**

```
a.tooltips {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
a.tooltips span {
  position: absolute;
  width:140px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #000000;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
a.tooltips span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -8px;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  border-right: 8px solid #000000;
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
}
a:hover.tooltips span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.8;
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a shorter version that I use:

```
PIAPP.directive('piTooltip', function(){
    return function($scope, element, attrs){
        element.append('<u>'+attrs.piTooltip+'</u>');
    };
});
```

CSS:

```
*[pi-tooltip]>u{
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    background: #f6e6c2;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    color: #000;
    z-index: 1000;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2em;
    left: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s linear 0.5s, visibility 0s;
}
*[pi-tooltip]:hover>u{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

You can use it in any container (a, span, div, etc) like this:

```
<div pi-tooltip="The content that I want to show">...</div>
```

Show the demo no [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5yhg5b0g/)